# Accessing local state using PyTEAL

Tags: python, sdk, state, algorand, pyteal

I'm having some trouble accessing the local state using PyTeal.

I'm trying to store a value in the local state of an account that has opted-in to the smart contract this way:

```
App.localPut(Int(0),Bytes("owner"), account_1)
```

, where account_1 is an

```
Algorand address
```

and this transaction works fine.

Now, I'm trying to send a NoOp transaction from

```
account_1
```

, and passing 1 address in the accounts array - the account that sent the transaction above.

The issue:

```
is_owner = Txn.sender() == App.localGet(Int(1), Bytes("owner"))
```

is_owner always returns false.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using the correct encoding of the address you're storing.

Are you using the 32 byte public key (not the 58 byte key)?

Try using the `decode_address` function on the 58 byte key, and you will receive the 32 byte key. That should work.